# What does those symbol mean in a git pull?

Tags: git, git-bash

[Example from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCnEC.png)

for example:

> 27 ++++--

what does 27, 4'+', and 2'-' mean?

hi, thanks, but i want to know why its 4x + and 1x - (++++-) not 8x + and 2x -(++++++++--) sometimes i see ++-- why it is not +- (50%:50%),?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `git` a **`+`** means an addition and **`-`** means a deletion.

In the image you've attached `25 ++++-`; there were a total of 25 changes of which (approximately)`4x`was addition of lines and `1x` was removal of line(s). Here `x = 5`
And in the next line `14 ++-` There were around 2x addition of lines and 1x deletion of line(s).

Here's a `git` diff for better understanding:

```
diff --git a/Src/Device_Config.c b/Src/Device_Config.c
index 05116f6..b177430 100644
--- a/Src/Device_Config.c
+++ b/Src/Device_Config.c
@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@

 #include "Device_Config.h"
-#include "userInterface.h"
+#include "UserInterface.h"
 #include "wifi.h"
 #include "Log.h"
 #include "Timezones.h"
```

As you can see one line was `deleted` and one line was `added`.

Comment: hi, thanks, but i want to know why its 4x + and 1x - (++++-) not 8x + and 2x -(++++++++--)  sometimes i see ++-- why it is not +- (50%:50%),?

Comment: @huhao it's the ratio of added and removed lines. Have a look at the SO question this is a duplicate of.

Comment: thank you, i think i've got it